# Assigning text to dropdown buttons in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having problems while assigning values to dropdown buttons and also getting their values while I do a POST request.

```
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-ledger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Ledger
    <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">With Margin</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Without Margin</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-company-code dropdown-toggle" id = "company_code" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Company Code
    <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">EA</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">EAC</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">ROC</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-cost-centre dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Cost centre
    <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">ALL</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">NSE-EQ</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-type dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Type
    <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CLNT</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">GENL</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">MARG</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id = "submit" class="btn btn-success">
                <i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-large"></i> Submit
    </button>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="../static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(".dropdown-menu").click(function(){

      $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
      $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());

   });

    $('#submit').on('click', function(event) {
        url = '/ledger/data'
        alert($("company_code").attr('value'));
 // event.preventDefault(); // To prevent following the link (optional)
      $.post(url,function(response){
        alert(response);
      });
});
    </script>
  </body>
```

What I want is the text of a button to change when a drop down value is selected. Currently, when I select a value, text of all the buttons change. How do I stop that?

When I click on the submit button, I want the current value of all the buttons. Currently it returns undefined. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: try with `$('#button').text();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(".dropdown-menu li").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.btn-group').children('a').text($(this).text())
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3aXR6/)

Comment: Thanks! That works. Any particular reason why the Submit on click responds with a undefined?

Comment: @Hick looks like it should be `alert($("#company_code").text());` http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3aXR6/2/